"Undefined" when attempting analytical expression for a RegionIntersection and its Area in V14.0
I know I can obtain the Area  of a Region, both numerically and symbolically, for example:
Area@Ellipsoid[{0,0},{a,b}]
(* a*b*Pi *)

How can I get the same for the RegionIntersection of two regions?
Let's say I have two regions
ClearAll[reg1,reg2];
reg1[h_, r_] := Cylinder[
    {
        {0,0,h/2},
        {0,0,-h/2}
    }
    , r
];
reg2[a_] := InfinitePlane[
    {0,0,0},
    {
        {0,1,0}, 
        {Cos[a], 0, Sin[a]}
    }
];


Animate[
    With[
        {
            h=2,
            r=1
        },
        Graphics3D[ {reg1[h,r], reg2[a]} ]
    ]//Evaluate
    ,{a, 0, Pi/4}
]


I would like to have an analytical symbolic expression for the intersection of these two regions and their area.
If I calculate it with specific values, I do get a reasonable output.
Assuming[
    And[
        0 < a < Pi/8,
        Element[h, PositiveReals]
        Element[r, PositiveReals]
    ],
    With[
        {
            a=Pi/16,
            h=100,
            r=1
        },
        Area[
            RegionIntersection[
                reg1[h, r],
                reg2[a]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]


But I get undefined otherwise:
Assuming[
    And[
        0 < a < Pi/8,
        Element[h, PositiveReals]
        Element[r, PositiveReals]
    ],
    With[
        {},
        Area[
            RegionIntersection[
                reg1[h, r],
                reg2[a]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
(* Undefined*)

I'm using Wolfram Engine 14.0. Can't test on Wolfram Cloud because the computation exceeds the time limit for free accounts.
$Version
(* 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 21, 2023) *)

Am I missing a way to obtain symbolic expressions both for the region definition and its calculated quantities?
Is there a method to go from a Region to a symbolic condition,  something like the inverse of ImplicitRegion, which goes from a condition to a Region?

Your code
Assuming[ And[0 < a < Pi/8,  Element[h, PositiveReals] Element[r, PositiveReals]], 
With[{}, Area[RegionIntersection[reg1[h, r], reg2[a]]]]]

works in 14.1 on Windows 10, resulting in

Piecewise[{{Pi*r^2*Sqrt[1 + Tan[a]^2], (h < 0 && Inequality[h/(2*r), Less, Tan[a], Less, -1/2*h/r]) ||  (h > 0 && Inequality[-1/2*h/r, Less, Tan[a], Less, h/(2*r)])}},  (r*Abs[h]*Cot[a]*(h*Sqrt[4 - (h^2*Cot[a]^2)/r^2] + 4*r*ArcCsc[(2*r*Tan[a])/h]*Tan[a])*Sqrt[1 + Tan[a]^2])/(2*h)]

Also, based on @azerbajdzan also in 13.0.1. This may be a bug in 14.0.
Addition. The code
reg = Assuming[
  And[
   0 < a < Pi/8, 
   Element[h, PositiveReals],
   Element[r, PositiveReals]
  ],
  RegionIntersection[reg1[h, r], reg2[a]]
 ];
 RegionConvert[reg, "Implicit"]

produces
ImplicitRegion[  r >= 0 && h != 0 &&    0 <= 1/2 - \[FormalZ]/h <= 1 && \[FormalX]^2 + \[FormalY]^2 <=     r^2 && \[FormalZ] == \[FormalX] Tan[      a], {\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]}]

Unfortunately,
reg1 = RegionConvert[reg,     "Implicit"] /. {\[FormalX] -> x, \[FormalY] -> y, \[FormalZ] -> z,     h -> 1, r -> 1, a -> 3/10};RegionMember[reg1, {x, y, z}]

fails. The input
(x|y|z)\[Element]\DoubleStruckCapitalR]&&0<=1/2-z<=1&&x^2+y^2<=1&&z==x Tan[3/10]

is returned.

Thanks, can you get a symbolic expression for the region definition?

@rhemans: The code reg = Assuming[    And[0 < a < Pi/8,      Element[h, PositiveReals]  Element[r, PositiveReals]],     RegionIntersection[reg1[h, r], reg2[a]]];RegionConvert[reg, "Implicit"] produces ImplicitRegion[  r >= 0 && h != 0 &&    0 <= 1/2 - \[FormalZ]/h <= 1 && \[FormalX]^2 + \[FormalY]^2 <=     r^2 && \[FormalZ] == \[FormalX] Tan[      a], {\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]}].

Ok, I think I need to move to 14.1 . Thanks

Unfortunately, re1 = RegionConvert[reg,     "Implicit"] /. {\[FormalX] -> x, \[FormalY] -> y, \[FormalZ] -> z,     h -> 1, r -> 1, a -> 3/10};RegionMember[reg1, {x, y, z}] fails (The input is returned.).

Good, I was missing RegionConvert and RegionMember, even if they fail in this example case. If you put that in your answer I will accept it, provided there is nothing more complete by then.

This outputs the result after quite some time.
reg1[h_, r_] := Cylinder[{{0, 0, h/2}, {0, 0, -h/2}}, r];
reg2[a_] := 
  InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {Cos[a], 0, Sin[a]}}];

Assuming[{a, h, r} \[Element] Reals, 
 RegionIntersection[reg1[h, r], reg2[a]] // Area]




What version are you using? I have 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 21, 2023) (Wolfram Engine) and I get Undefined with your code, as well as with mine.

Version 13.0.1 and it took about 3 minutes.

Interesting, perhaps this is a 14.0 bug then.
